# What is the best way to render 胸怀 in 据说鲁肃这个人胸怀文韬武略...?

Tags: meaning

What is the best way to render 胸怀？

据说鲁肃这个人胸怀文韬武略，
It is/was said, Lu Su this man has/had great knowledge of military matters
而且老谋深算，孙权特别看重他。
moreover  is/was very astute, Sun Quan holds/held him in great esteem.

I have these definitions for 胸怀, but really, I just want to write 'has or had' for 胸怀.

1. 心中、心里头
2. 思想境界，指志趣、气度、抱负等
3. 心里怀著

Comment: 胸怀 can be used as a verb, meaning 胸中怀有.

Comment: Oxford loves **cherish** for 胸怀.

Answer (score 5):

'胸' is metaphor for "one's mind (brain)"

[胸怀 (verb) mind contains= **possess**]

[文韬武略 (object) theoretical and practical military knowledge]

> 据说鲁肃这个人**胸怀**文韬武略
>
> It was said that this man, Lu Su, **possessed** great military knowledge

胸怀 in other context can also mean 'have ~ within one's heart/ mind'

Example:

- **胸怀**大志 (**possess** great ambition/ **have** great ambition **within** one's heart/ mind )

Answer (score 0):

a fancy piece of writing’ just means he “has”, it’s a verb